# Update textbox with process output

Tags: c#, wpf, batch-file

I am trying to update a text box with the output of a bat file.

On a button click, I run my bat file.

```
{
proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"E:\comm.bat";

proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

proc.ErrorDataReceived += DataReceived;
proc.OutputDataReceived += DataReceived;

proc.Start();

proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();

proc.WaitForExit();
}
```

and

```
void DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data != null)
    {
        textBox1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new SetText(UpdateText(e.Data)));

    }
}
```

and

```
public delegate void SetText();

public void UpdateText(String str)
{
  textBox1.AppendText = str;
}
```

`e.Data` contains the string which i want to update in `TextBox`.
How to pass `e.Data` to `UpdateText`?

I am getting error

> error CS1656: Cannot assign to 'AppendText' because it is a 'method
>   group'
>
> error CS0149: Method name expected

How i can make it work?
Thanks

Comment: Are you not going to load a secondary command processor? What output do you expect to capture?

Comment: I simply wants the output of batch file in my textbox.

Comment: @Garry, please suggest how to get output of batch file in textbox.

Comment: Many would load a secondary command processor with /c.  But if it works, then all's well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190824%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) executes the specified delegate asynchronously with the specified array of arguments on the thread the `Dispatcher` is associated with. You are doing it in a wrong way. Try this

```
    void DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            textBox1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new SetText(UpdateText), DispatcherPriority.Normal, e.Data);            }
    }
```

Comment: What did you fix?  Can you explain?

Comment: error CS0149: Method name expected. I have fixed this error which occurs at this line of OP question `textBox1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new SetText(UpdateText(e.Data)));`

Comment: Thanks, it looked like a code-only answer with no explanation.

Comment: @GarryVass i have updated my answer. Thanks for notifying me. It's my mistake.

Comment: It looks like the improved answer attracted an up vote.  Well done!

Comment: Thanks Muhammad Umar, Garry Vass, Mathew

Comment: @MuhammadUmar, I am getting the textbox updated only after batch file gets completed, and it looks like it got hanged for some time.

Comment: Got it working by putting proc.WaitForExit(); in another thread

Answer (score 3):

AppendText is a method thats why you get the error. If you want to assign the string you should do:

```
textBox1.Text = str;
```

if you want to append it:

```
textBox1.AppendText(str);
```

Comment: thanks @javi, In Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() method name is expected.

Answer (score 0):

The way you try to call the method on the dispatcher is wrong.You'll need to invest more effort into learning `C#` basics before fiddling with `WPF`. With that said, the error,

> error CS1656: Cannot assign to 'AppendText' because it is a 'method group'

can be resolved by using `Text` instead of `AppendText`:

```
textBox1.Text = str;
```

The error,

> error CS0149: Method name expected

can be resolved by,

```
textBox1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
                                new Action(() => UpdateText(e.Data)),
                                DispatcherPriority.Normal);
```

You don't need to declare new delegate type.